# place button at the right of div

Tags: html, css

here is how my screen should look like:

the orange button should be on the right of the "dashboard-detail-body" and have margins to the top, left, and bottom ("dashboard-container")
[image]

this is what I tried:

```
   <div class="dashboard-detail-body">

        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 15px;">
            {{ui-5/button label="click me"}}
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-container">
```

but I do not get the desired behavior - no margin bottom (the orange button is overlapping with the bottom div)
[image]

margin-bottom, did not solve it, how can I get the desired behavior?

Comment: can you send some more code?

Comment: ^ This provided code doesn't reproduce the issue

Comment: This happens because you've applied `float: right` (to the button) without defining `overflow:auto` (or `hidden`) to its parent element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `float: right;` style. This makes the element overlap.
You can solve this issue by using flex-box, with the following code:

```
.dashboard-detail-body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.align-right{
    align-self: flex-end;
}

<div class="dashboard-detail-body">
    <div class="align-right">
        I am right
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-container">
        <p>a<p>
        <p>b<p>
        <p>c<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it was difficult to understand and recreate your problem from the available data, I assume that you want to align a button center-right inside the container. You can use `flexbox` to align elements inside a parent.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
}

button.orange {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  
  /*  optional basic styling  */
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="orange">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with css grid:

```css
.dashboard-detail-body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 2em;

}
.right{
  justify-self: end;
  margin: 1em 3em 1em 1em;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
}
.dashboard-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  width: 95%;
  height: 200px;
}
.dashboard-container > p {
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-detail-body">
    <div class="right">
        click me
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-container">
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are shrinking your div with float right it frees space on the left. The clear property doesn't work.
So the solution I came up with is to keep the div full & use a button

```css
.dashboard-detail-body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 40rem;
  min-width: 45rem;
  margin: auto;
}
.btn-area {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
}
.btn {
  background: #ff9900;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #9c7842;
  /*   clear: left; */
  /*   display: inline-block; */
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.dashboard-container {
  border: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*   align-items: center; */
}
.box {
  border: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
  width: 6.5rem;
  height: 6.5rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-detail-body">

  <div class="btn-area">
    <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```